# Creating a calculated field in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a tricky PowerBI problem that I'm hoping for some help with.

The data are as follows:

| Product | Year | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'Book' | 2020 | 24 |
| 'Book' | 2021 | 15 |
| 'Book' | 2022 | 10 |
| 'TV' | 2020 | 42 |
| 'TV' | 2021 | 48 |
| 'TV' | 2022 | 33 |
| 'PC' | 2020 | 130 |
| 'PC' | 2021 | 115 |
| 'PC' | 2022 | 170 |

I need help firstly making a calculated field that shows the percentage of growth/decline in each category year on year for the two most recent years (2021 and 2022 in this case). The change should be calculated as follows:

**=(MostRecentYear - PreviousYear)/PreviousYear**

2021 and 2022 can be specified if required, but would prefer to use MAX and MAX-1 to determine it so that I don't need to update code every year. If that's possible of course... It would also be great if the result can be expressed as a percentage and limited to one decimal place as per the table below.

Secondly, I need to include all these data in a matrix in the following format:

| Product | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Book' | 24 | 15 | 10 | -33.3% |
| 'TV' | 42 | 48 | 33 | -31.3% |
| 'PC' | 130 | 115 | 170 | 47.8% |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the results in a matrix then % Change will necessarily appear for each year alongside the purchases for that year. It can be set to return a blank for all but the end (subtotal) column, though it cannot be removed as a field. If this is not to your liking then you'd have to use a normal table visual instead, though that would require individual measures defining for each of the years, which would not be very flexible. Please confirm your preference.

Comment: Besides what @Jos Wooley wrote, you can just hide the % for 2021/2020 and turn off auto-size columns or use calculation groups in tabular editor.  Otherwise, the percentage fields will be shown for every YOY calculation. If you are going to always display only 3 years, you can calculate each field separately. That shouldn't cause performance issues at all.

Comment: Seems like Power Query can easily do this for you.

https://powerbi.tips/2016/06/dynamic-percent-change-using-dax/

Comment: Thank you all. @JosWoolley I would be willing to try the second option. The format is the most important thing, so I need to avoid having the calculations for each year.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following three measures:

```
Total_Purchases =
SUM ( 'Table'[Purchases] )

% Change =
VAR Most_Recent_Year =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Year] ),
        ALL ( 'Table'[Year] )
    )
VAR Previous_Year = Most_Recent_Year - 1
VAR Purchases_Most_Recent_Year =
    CALCULATE (
        [Total_Purchases],
        'Table'[Year] = Most_Recent_Year
    )
VAR Purchases_Previous_Year =
    CALCULATE (
        [Total_Purchases],
        'Table'[Year] = Previous_Year
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        Purchases_Most_Recent_Year - Purchases_Previous_Year,
        Purchases_Previous_Year
    )

2020 =
CALCULATE ( [Total_Purchases], 'Table'[Year] = 2020 )
```

Duplicate the last measure as required for other relevant years. Add all measures to a standard table visual.